# Detect HLS audio canplay event

Tags: javascript, jquery, nginx, http-live-streaming

I'm using nginx and nginx rtmp module to create audio stream for mobile. For video I use ffmpeg to slice video to jpeg images, and that way I display video stream to mobile users. Audio is going separate which causes audio latency of 15-30 seconds. I assume that this happens because video of jpegs starts before audio buffers. So what I tried is to catch `<audio>`  event "canplay" and when this event fires, then to start the video preview.

Audio source example: http://example.com:8081/hls/audio.m3u8

The code for detection:

```
 var audio = document.getElementById('preview-audio');
 audio.oncanplay=function(){ console.log('audio loaded'); };
```

but this event never fires. Only events that fire are "loadstart" and "progress". How can I detect that audio is buffered so that I can sync it with jpeg's?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use the `oncanplaythrough` event.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("preview-audio");
audio.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    console.log("Audio can be played.");
};
```

More info on `oncanplaythrough` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp).